# ActionMode custom background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionmode

How can we change the layout or background of an `ActionMode` ? there is method`actionMode.getCustomView();`but always returns null . is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change it through styles.xml with this attribute

```
 <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
 <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
```

ASAIK changing it programmatically is not yet supported

Comment: what is min API support of this ?

Comment: it is backward compatible using actionbarcompat, @JCodex

Answer (score 2):

I wanna make more clearer this answer. First create custom background "storage_list_header_shape.xml" in your drawable folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle" >

   <gradient
      android:angle="270"
      android:startColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
      android:centerColor="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
      android:endColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />

   <size android:height="3dp" />

 </shape>
```

Second, create custom style in your style.xml

```
<style name="customActionModeTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/storage_list_header_shape</item>
</style>
```

Third, call the style in your manifest.

```
<activity
     android:name="com.javacafe.activities.Main"
     android:launchMode="singleTop"
     android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
     android:theme="@style/customActionModeTheme" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change the  background of an `ActionMode`,you should use the `actionMode.setCustomView(View yourView)`,then you can transfer the `yourView` variable to the method.

Comment: yes but the added view only affect the empty part of the ActionMode ,not the whole bar.

Comment: you want to change the whole action bar?